# Calculator Codes for Squareroot and Decimals

Tags: vb.net

Here's a picture of my Calculator design

[image]

I've been trying other code to work with my calculator but they haven't worked and I'm in need of code for decimal and square root. I'm still new to programming. The way that I did it was the long way. I've heard that there's some short way of doing it but it was confusing

```
Dim Firstnum As Decimal
Dim secondnum As Decimal
Dim Operations As Integer
Dim Operator_selctor As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "1"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "1"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "2"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "2"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "3"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "3"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "4"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "4"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "5"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "5"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "6"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "6"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "7"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "7"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "8"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "8"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "9"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "9"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    If TextBox1.Text <> "0" Then
        TextBox1.Text += "0"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button16_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button16.Click
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
End Sub

Private Sub Button11_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    If Not (TextBox1.Text.Contains(".")) Then
        TextBox1.Text += "."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button15_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
    Firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
    Operator_selctor = True
    Operations = 1 ' = +    
End Sub

Private Sub Button14_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click
    Firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
    Operator_selctor = True
    Operations = 2 ' - -
End Sub

Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    Firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
    Operator_selctor = True
    Operations = 3 '=x

End Sub

Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    Firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
    Operator_selctor = True
    Operations = 4 ' /
End Sub

Private Sub Button18_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
    If Operator_selctor = True Then
        secondnum = TextBox1.Text
        If Operations = 1 Then
            TextBox1.Text = Firstnum + secondnum
        ElseIf Operations = 2 Then
            TextBox1.Text = Firstnum - secondnum
        ElseIf Operations = 3 Then
            TextBox1.Text = Firstnum * secondnum
        Else
            If secondnum = 0 Then
                TextBox1.Text = "Error!"
            Else
                TextBox1.Text = Firstnum / secondnum
            End If
        End If
        Operator_selctor = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [Ask] and reformulate your question.

Comment: Look inside the `Math` namespace for mathematical functions like square root. `Math.Sqrt`. Pleae explain what you mean by decimals.

Comment: So Button7 adds 1, Button6 adds 4, and Button3 adds 6. Could you make this any more confusing?

Comment: If you learn nothing else from this exercise, I hope you learned to give your controls meaningful names. Also, please use &= so anyone, even with the quickest glance will see that you are concatenating strings not doing addition.